# How can I disable the bounce and page refresh on pulling down from the top of the screen on iOS?

Tags: javascript, css, ios

I'm trying to develop a full-screen 3D web app and this is very undesirable behavior.

I'm using CSS and JavaScript.

There are already questions relating to this on StackOverflow but none of the solutions work - perhaps outdated?

I have tried
`overscroll-behavior: none;`
but it did nothing.

I have tried the techniques in this web page https://www.bram.us/2016/05/02/prevent-overscroll-bounce-in-ios-mobilesafari-pure-css/

They also did nothing.

Is it simply impossible?

Note: I still need scrolling and interaction with the page to be possible. I just want to turn off the bounce and refresh effect.

Answer (score 0):

prevent touch and mouse down

```
function preventEvent(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}


window.addEventListener("touchstart", preventEvent, { passive: false })
window.addEventListener("mousedown", preventEvent)
```

Comment: This turns off all input, I still need button clicks and the ability to scroll. Just want to turn off the bounce.